# applying same function to many elements (in order)

Tags: javascript, jquery

any better way to do that (assuming I have 10 `a` elements, for instance)?

```
$('#id > a:nth-child(1)').click(function() { changeP(1); return false; });
$('#id > a:nth-child(2)').click(function() { changeP(2); return false; });
$('#id > a:nth-child(3)').click(function() { changeP(3); return false; });
```

I know 2 possibilities, but I don't particularly like them:

1. using `.bind()` with parameter instead of `.click()`
2. using `.map(return $(this))` and then iterating over the array with an index var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('#id > a').each(function(i) {
  $(this).click(function() { changeP(i); return false; });
});
```

jQuery will pass in the index of the selected element as the first parameter to the "each" function.

Comment: +1 better than `index()`, which has to walk across all the sibling elements counting them to work out how many there are.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the index of an element (relative to it's parent) using the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
$("#id > a").click(function() {
    changeP($(this).index() + 1);
    return false;
});
```

You need to add 1 because element indexes start at 0, whereas `nth-child` starts at 1. This works because jQuery methods tend to apply to all elements in the matched set, so the `click` event handler is bound to all elements matching the selector.

Comment: What if there are other elements (no `a`s) in between? Wouldn't that result in a wrong index?

Comment: You can "steal" part of my answer ;) (caching the selected elements and do `$a.index(this)`). Or you could to `$(this).index("#id > a")`.

Comment: Actually, I think my current answer is correct, as the `nth-child` selector (as used in the question) will only return an element if the element at the specified index matches the selector, which implies there can't be any other elements in between (although, perhaps after the first 3 there could... so maybe you are right after all :))

Comment: You are right... :) At least we have considered every possibility ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#id > a').click(function(){
    changeP($(this).index(' #id > a')+1);
    return false;
});
```

See: [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

This works even if other elements are inserted into the code:

```
<div id="id">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <span>hello</span>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This will get the index relative to all `a` elements, not only `#id > a`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each( $('#id > a'), function(index) { 
  $(this).click(function() { 
   changeP(index); return false; });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for .each(): http://api.jquery.com/each/

```
$('#id > a').each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(){
        changeP(index+1);
    });
});
```